# Flutter Map - How can I let the user draw a circle?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, maps, fluttermap

I'm trying to let the user drag across the screen to draw a circle. initial point of the drag would set the center and the final point of the drag would set the radius.

I know I could easily do this with two taps, first tap for center, second for radius, but I'd really like to get the drag working if possible.

This is what I have so far. It kiiiind of works but the user has to (a) release their finger after the first long press (b) pan the map to set the size of the circle. Ideally the map camera should be locked in place while the circle is drawn.

```
Widget _displayMap() {
    return FlutterMap(
      mapController: createMapController,
      options: MapOptions(
        onLongPress: (tapPosition, latLng) {
          if (circleSelected) {
            print("setting center");
            setState(() {
              circleCenter = latLng;
              mapCircle = CircleMarker(
                point: latLng,
                radius: 0.0,
                color: isLightMode ? colourPrimaryTrans : colourSecondaryTransDark,
                borderColor: isLightMode ? colourPrimary : colourSecondaryDark,
                borderStrokeWidth: 5,
              );
            });
          }
        },
        onPositionChanged: (position, bool hasGesture) {
          if (circleSelected && circleCenter != null && hasGesture) {
            double radius = const Distance().as(LengthUnit.Meter, circleCenter!, position.center!);
            print("setting radius");
            setState(() {
              mapCircle = CircleMarker(
                point: circleCenter!,
                radius: radius,
                color: isLightMode ? colourPrimaryTrans : colourSecondaryTransDark,
                borderColor: isLightMode ? colourPrimary : colourSecondaryDark,
                borderStrokeWidth: 5,
              );
            });
          }
        },
      )
    )
  }
```

Edit:
Here is a GIF of where this part of my code currently stands:
https://imgur.com/a/3iuIZVJ

I have changed it to the following, but still want to implement a drag action.

```
if(circleSelected){
                  if(circleFirstClick){
                    mapCircleSetting = null;
                    circleCenterSetting = latLng;
                    circleFirstClick = false;
                    circleCenterMarker = Marker(
                      rotate: true,
                      point: circleCenterSetting!, 
                      child: OverflowBox(maxHeight: 100, maxWidth:200,
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: [
                            Icon(Icons.location_on, color: isLightMode? colourPrimary:colourPrimaryDark,),
                            const Text(
                                  "Center",
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                ),
                          ]
                        ),
                      )
                      );
                  } else {
                    circleFirstClick = true;
                    mapRadiusSetting = const Distance().as(LengthUnit.Meter, circleCenterSetting!, latLng);
                    mapCircleSetting = CircleMarker(
                      point: circleCenterSetting!,
                      useRadiusInMeter: true,
                      radius: mapRadiusSetting!,
                      color: isLightMode ? colourPrimaryTrans : colourPrimaryTransDark,
                      borderColor: isLightMode ? colourPrimary : colourPrimaryDark,
                      borderStrokeWidth: 5,
                    ); 
                  }
                }
```

Comment: Do you need it to have real gps coordinates or just a drawing of a circle on top of it?

Comment: @AprendendoNext it needs real gps coordinates

Comment: @RJrules64 can your provide final output result screen shot or GIF? so better to understand..

Comment: There is multiple ways like add circle button when user press that button then add circle automatically add to this map and user can drag that circle or somthing like we can add sticker of circle user can drag or resize that circle. please give me details of your task

Comment: @JeelBhatti Here is a GIF of how it currently works, I tap to place a center marker and then tap where the edge of the circle should go. https://imgur.com/a/3iuIZVJ
I want the final product to look just like that but to be a drag action instead of 2 taps. the user should be able to see the circle resizing as they drag